# SQL query to update a column with a random text value from an array of 4 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my table that I want to update each row with text selected randomly from  an array of 4 values
array = {value1, value2, value3, value4}
is there a query to select one random value d=from the array then update the field ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Explain where the "array" is coming from.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't natively support arrays.  Is your `array` actually a string/varchar containing some json?  If so, it's worth noting that `{}` isn't for arrays, it's for objects/structs/dictionaries, meaning your example would be malformed even if it were meant to me a json string.

Comment: the array is not coming from anywhere I added a new column to my DB that should be filled by the user selection from a drop_down list in the next release, but for now to test I need to update the column by these 4 values

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this in a single update:

```
with vals as (
      select v.val, count(*) over () as num_vals,
             row_number() over (order by val) - 1 as seqnum
      from (values ('val1'), ('val2'), ('val3'), ('val4')) v(val)
     )
update t
    set t.d = v.val
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (order by newid()) - 1 as seqnum
          from t
         ) t join
         vals
         on vals.seqnum = t.seqnum % vals.cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by running below query 4 times each time with a different value to cover all 4 values      {value1, value2, value3, value4}

```
   DECLARE @Counter INT , @Rand INT 
SET @Counter=1
SET @Rand= FLOOR(RAND()*(1476-1+1))+1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 400)
BEGIN
    update Table set ConfidentialityLevel = 'Value1'   where ID = @Rand
    print @Rand
    SET @Rand= FLOOR(RAND()*(1476-1+1))+1
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```